# Changing URL Location in an Android App

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I am making a call to a RESTful Webservice from my Activity in Android.  The URL is specified as a string resource.  But what I don't understand is, after a few months chances are I will be changing the URL.  How do I ensure that the phones that have old URL get the new URL?

(Needless to say I am a newbie to Android.)

Comment: Put updates to your application on market.

Answer (score 0):

Have your app check for "URL is old" errors when making requests, when you switch to a new URL and return the error on the old URL and have the app prompt users to update to the latest version.